# Typescript reports error when trying to instantiate a parameter that is a class

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface CreatorInterface {
  create(initData: {[key: string]: any}): object;
}

interface FactoryInterface {
  creators: {[key: string]: CreatorInterface};

  registerCreator(identifier: string, creatorClass: CreatorInterface): boolean;
}

export class Factory implements FactoryInterface {
  creators: {[key: string]: CreatorInterface} = {}

  registerCreator(identifier: string, creatorClass: CreatorInterface): boolean {
    this.creators[identifier] = new creatorClass()

    return true
  }
}
```

The problem is that **VisualStudioCode** reports the following typescript error:

[image]

How can I indicate TypeScript that a parameter is a class that can be instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a class *constructor* is not the same as the type of the class *instance*.  A class constructor is `new`-able and therefore needs a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) which returns the instance type of the class.  The constructor does not contain the instance members.

The type named `CreatorInterface` is presumably your instance type, and not appropriate for the `creatorClass` parameter of `registerCreator()`.  Instead, you intend to write `new creatorClass()`... so you want the type to be `new () => CreatorInterface` instead:

```
interface FactoryInterface {
    creators: { [key: string]: CreatorInterface };
    registerCreator(
        identifier: string, 
        creatorClass: new () => CreatorInterface): boolean;
}

export class Factory implements FactoryInterface {
    creators: { [key: string]: CreatorInterface } = {}

    registerCreator(
        identifier: string, 
        creatorClass: new () => CreatorInterface
    ): boolean {
        this.creators[identifier] = new creatorClass()    
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJQnMB7KBJcaeJZAbwChkrkEMsIAKUYMAESzgC4zkBtAawgBPbgGcwUUAHMAutzgghyAL4BKbtgBGAKwgIwAbnLLy5UJFiIUAMUQ4oQgheIoK1GnXujupPoJHI4pIgstzomPZORFYqRu4YUsDi0OFYuEwAJhDgwDDA0GIS0gA0HhG4qAA2cKLeyCAQAO7IDKrIALwAfGieuFGWSOrImtjYlZggRibkEAAeAA64YDTVtci2+rhKwAC28+M72WCi63Zb-S5klNS05VB1vgLChcGhPXcXMcodZNPxEIlklBUvZMkdcvkoC8SmU0sDVnUGs1Wh1uiC+oQBhAhiMxhMru53GAABZJAB0tzhol4wCyOTy0BkPyRsPsVRqolapkJ1AwYAArlAQMgJPyINcqCZlEA)